# Two constructors?

Tags: java, constructor, compiler-errors, getter, setter

I already did my assignment with setters and getters (I did this with OOD) however I still don't understand what's the purpose of the two `Rectangle` methods and if ever I remove the empty `Rectangle` an error will prompt:

[image]

P.S. This is not the full code.

```
// private double length = 25.0;
private double width = 15.5;

public Rectangle(){

}

public Rectangle(double length, double width){
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
}

public void setDimension(double length,double width){
    this.length = length;
    this.width=width;
}

public double getLength(){
    return length;
}

public double getWidth(){
    return width;
}

public double area(){
    return length * width;
}

public double perimeter(){
    return 2 * (length + width);
}

public static void print(){
    Rectangle rt = new Rectangle();
    Box box = new Box();
    System.out.println("The rectangle has a length of " + rt.getLength() + " and a width of " + rt.getWidth() );
    System.out.println("The rectangle has an area of "+ rt.area());
    System.out.println("The rectangle has a perimeter of "+ rt.perimeter());
    box.print();
}
```

Comment: It is an empty no-args constructor which you call via `new Rectangle()`, wether it makes sense to have it is debatable but not on SO.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the default (no-arg) constructor. Since you have another constructor, Java **will not** implicitly create it if you don't define it explicitly. Since the first line in your `print` method calls it, you'll get an error if you remove it.